# chess game - error in abstract class

Tags: c++, abstract, chess

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Chess_tool
{
public:
    Chess_tool(string color, char name); 
    virtual bool legal_movement(int source[], int dest[]) const = 0;

private:
    string _color;
    char _name;
};
```

Im trying to create chess game, so I create abstract class for chess tool (queen, king, rook...)
I also created king tool to check my code:

```
#pragma once

#include "Chess_tool.h"

class King : Chess_tool
{
public:
    King(string color, char name);
    virtual bool legal_movement(int source[], int dest[]);
};
```

and I create game_board class:

```
#pragma once
#include "Game_board.h"
#include "Chess_tool.h"
#include <iostream>

#define BOARD_SIZE 8
using namespace std;

class Chess_tool;
class Game_board
{
public:
    Game_board();
    ~Game_board();
    void move(string panel);


protected:
    Chess_tool* _board[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
};
```

the problem is here, when i try to add object to the matrix its show me error  : 
    1   IntelliSense: object of abstract class type "King" is not allowed:
            pure virtual function "Chess_tool::legal_movement" has no overrider

```
#pragma once
#include "Chess_tool.h"
#include "Game_board.h"
#include "King.h"
using namespace std;

enum Turn { WIHTE, BLACK };

class Manager : Game_board
{
public:
    Manager();
    ~Manager();
    virtual bool legal_movement(int source[], int dest[]) const = 0;
};
```

....

```
#include "Manager.h"
Manager::Manager()
{
    _board[0][0] = new King();
}
```

Comment: Try to compile your code. IntelliSense errors can be caused by fact that code wasn't indexed yet.

Comment: Are you aware you're using private inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

The member function in the base class is const-qualified, not in the derived class.

So these are **not the same** functions through inheritance. You've declared a new virtual function, not overriden the first one.

Add `const` to the second one so that it actually override the base class function.

Remember that for virtual function overriding to kick in, there are a few condition to actually satisfy. They must have:

- the same name
- the same return type
- the same parameters count and type
- the same const-qualification (our case here)
- a few other minor things (for example, compatible exceptions specifications)

If any condition isn't satisfied, you create a very similar, but different, function for the compiler.

With C++11, you should use `override` for the functions you want to override, so the compiler knows your intention and tells you that you've made a mistake. E.g.:

```
virtual bool legal_movement(int source[], int dest[]) override;
//                                                    ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: now when o try to run the progrem : 

     Manager::Manager()
 {
  Chess_tool *b = new King("black", 'p');
  _board[0][0] = b;

 }

its show me  : 
 - IntelliSense: conversion to inaccessible base class "Chess_tool" is not allowed
- error C2243: 'type cast' : conversion from 'King *' to 'Chess_tool *' exists, but is inaccessible

Comment: That's what @juanchopanza told you (and that I failed to notice), you're using private inheritance. And that doesn't create a "is-a" relationship between your class, that is mandatory for polymorphism, but a "has-a". Look up how to do proper inheritance to understand that more thoroughly.